# ROS CvBridge on gray image not working because of channel information

Tags: python, image, opencv, ros

## What I want

I wish to resize a gray image and publish this so I can use this in another ROS node. However I encounter a problem with the channel information, which is either OpenCV or CvBridge.

### Error

When listerning to a camera(webcam/kinect) and converting this to 'mono8' (gray) you get the following information(row, column, channels) in which channels = 1. For some reason if you save this image and read it again suddenly channels = 3. Why is this important? If you use cv2.resize(image,x,y) on an image with 3 channels the output image is (x,y,channels=3), however when there is only 1 channel, this information is lost and your output is (x,y). The problem with this is that CvBridge won't work without channel information.

The following code works, because cv2.resize is performed on 3 channels:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PKG = 'something'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rospy
import cv2
import sys
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw",Image, self.callback)
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("test_image",Image, self.callback2)
        self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("test_image", Image)
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

    def callback(self, image):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image, 'mono8')
        except CvBridgeError, e:
            print e
        
        print cv_image.shape ### output: (480, 640, 1)
        cv2.imshow("Test", cv_image)
        cv2.imwrite("Test.png", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)

        test2 = cv2.imread("Test.png")
        print test2.shape ### output: (480, 640, 3)
        cv2.imshow("Test 2",test2)
        cv2.waitKey(3)
        test2 = cv2.resize(test2,(250,240))
        print test2.shape ### output: (250, 240, 3)
        self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(test2))

    def callback2(self, image):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image)
        except CvBridgeError, e:
            print e
        
        cv2.imshow("Test3", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)

def main(args):
    test = Test()
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)

    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Shutting down"
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

However the following doesn't work (this time trying to publish the resize):

```
    print cv_image.shape ### output: (480, 640, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Test", cv_image)
    cv2.imwrite("Test.png", cv_image)
    cv2.waitKey(3)
    
    test2 = cv2.resize(test2,(250,240))
    print test2.shape ### output: (250, 240)
    self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(test2)) ### ERROR

    test2 = cv2.imread("Test.png")
    print test2.shape
    cv2.imshow("Test 2",test2)
    cv2.waitKey(3)
```

### Other Error

Changing 'mono8' to '8UC3' gives the following error: [yuv422] is a color format but [8UC3] is not so they must have the same OpenCV type, CV_8UC3, CV16UC1

## My real question

How can I resize a gray image and publish this in ROS without either losing channel information or converting it somehow to 3 channels? My only concern is that I can send the resized information, the number of channels is not important to me.

### Information

Ubuntu 12.04,
ROS Hydro,
OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: In the code that you say doesn't work, aren't you publishing `test2` without reading it first? `test2` seems to be empty when you're publishing it.

Comment: I should have been more clear with my example, but the issue is mostly already addressed here: [link](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/49)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the master branch of CvBridge it's now fixed that you can send images without channel information: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/49.

For the people who are not on the master branch:

```
#Ugly gray 3 channel hack for CvBridge (old version)
#Save image
cv2.imwrite(self.dir_image_save+'tempface.png', cv2_image)
#Load
cv2_image = cv2.imread(self.dir_image_save+'tempface.png')
```

Now you got a 3 channel gray image (but ugly).